# "Error in property <waypoints>"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api v3,

I store coordinates into an array and supply the whole array to the waypoints as below:

```
var request{
origin:start,
destination:end,
waypoints:arrayOfCoordinates,
}
```

When I run my code it gives me following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error in property <waypoints>: (Invalid value: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (Error in element at position 4: (Unknown property <x>)))
gen_204:-1Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the arguments, the fourth one, is missing.